# Php echo issue in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

i want to display my portfolio contents in fancybox. I could display the featured image but couldn't display text content. My codes which i used:

```
<div class="port-img fancybox" rel="gallery">
                                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $featured_img ); ?>" alt="Work"/><br/>
                                     <?php $postQuery->printText('general description-small'); ?>
                              </div>
```

And my full document is [here](http://codepad.org/IGXDK99R).

Comment: the `echo` is redundant. esc_url() already does its own echo internally. General rule of thumb, `get_whatever()` in WP returns something, `whatever()` does output automatically.

Comment: But this is not wordpress' official use. It's just theme extension which is called portfolio. And theme author has used this code for calling the description : `<?php $postQuery->printText('general description-small'); ?>` But i couldn't call it in fancybox. @MarcB

Comment: no need to use `ECHO` just use `<?php esc_url( $featured_img ); ?>`

Comment: the featured images of portfolio got lost. @devpro

Comment: `echo $featured_img` chk this, what u get?

Comment: Hey c'mon, `esc_url` just returns never echoes... Please know for sure before suggesting others...

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url

Comment: Yeah i got the featured image but this wasn't my aim my featured image has already displayed. I wanna get description. @devpro